# How do I get proc SQL to select minimum date as the missing date

Tags: sql, sas

In the data below I would like proc sql to select the minimum date for subject 123 as the missing date.

```
data visit;
  input subject $1-3  dtc $4-24 ;
  cards;
  123  2014-01-15T00:00
  123 
  123  2014-01-17T00:00:00
  124  2014-01-15T00:00:00
  124  2014-01-15T00:00:00
  124  2014-01-17T00:00:00
  ;
run;



proc sql;
 create table want. as
 select distinct subject, min(dtc) as mindt format = date9.
 from have
 where subject ne ''
 group by subject;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

`MIN()` will discard missing values from the aggregate computation.  Thus, you need to test separately if there are any missing values.

Example:

Use a `CASE` expression to calculate the `MIN` you want.

```
data have;
  input subject $1-3  dtc $5-27 ;
  cards;
123  2014-01-15T00:00
123  .
123  2014-01-17T00:00:00
124  2014-01-15T00:00:00
124  2014-01-15T00:00:00
124  2014-01-17T00:00:00
;

proc sql ;
 create table want as
 select 
   subject
  , case when nmiss(dtc) then '' else min(dtc) end as mindtc
  , input (calculated mindtc, ? yymmdd10.) as mindt format=date9.
 from have
 where subject ne ''
 group by subject
;
quit;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution in SAS:

First, create an index or sort your data by subject and dtc.

```
proc sort data=have out=have_sorted; 
  by subject dtc;
quit;
```

Then you can apply a data step with by grouping and use the *first.[column]* to get the minimum for each subject including missing values:

```
data minima;
  set have_sorted;
  by subject dtc;
  if first.subject;
run;
```